# CGI wont display variables through HTML in c (Eclipse)

Tags: html, c, variables, cgi

I have used a fifo pipe to read in some data (weather data) into a char variable. The console will display this variable correctly. However, when I try to display it through HTML on the CGI page, it simply does not display. Code below -

```
int main(void) {
    int fd;
    char *myfifo = "pressure.txt";
    char buff[BUFFER];
    long fTemp;

    //open and read message
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buff, BUFFER);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buff);
    close(fd);



    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
    puts("<HTML>");
    puts("<BODY>");
    printf("Data is:  %s", buff);
    puts("</BODY>");
    puts("</HTML>");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see in the console is displays correctly -

```
Received: 2014-08-13 16:54:57
25.0 DegC, 1018.7 mBar

Content-type: text/html

<HTML>
<BODY>
 Data is  2014-08-13 16:54:57
25.0 DegC, 1018.7 mBar
</BODY>
</HTML>
logout
```

But on the CGI webpage it does not display the weather data, but it does display "data is".

Comment: You can't print anything before the header, or it may be rendered wrong.

Comment: Also, is the text you read from the file descriptor zero terminated? Do you check what `read` returns? Do you check that `open` doesn't fail?

Comment: we tried moving all the code into the body but still no luck - printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
 puts("<HTML>");
 puts("<BODY>");
 //open and read message
 fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
 read(fd, buff, BUFFER);
 //printf("Received: %s\n", buff);
 close(fd);
 printf("Data is:  %s", buff);
 puts("</BODY>");
 puts("</HTML>");

Comment: we check what read returns through printf("Received: %s\n", buff); which displays correctly

Comment: Also, to be technically correct (even though most browsers should be able to handle it) you should end lines with `"\r\n"`.

Comment: And have you checked "View source"? Or used the browsers network inspector to see headers etc.?

Comment: View source shows <HTML>
<BODY>
Data is:  
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: Network inspector shows html>

    <head></head>
    <body>


        Data is:  


    </body>

</html>

Comment: Then, again, I ask you to actually *check* what `open` and `read` returns. Those functions can fail, and you have simply not idea about it in the program shown. My guess is that the current directory when the program is executed as a CGI is not what you expect, so your program can't find the file.  Use [`getcwd`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) to get the current working directory and print it.

Comment: open() returns a 3 integer in the debug (sorry I am a uni student and am learning).

Comment: Change the filename to a *full* path, e.g. `const char *myfifo = "/path/to/pressure.txt";` (where you replace `"/path/to/"` with the actual path).

Comment: The file is in a root directory of a microcontroller, its path in properties displays as sftp://root@10.0.0.2/root/pressure.txt

Comment: Well the working directory of the web-server which runs the CGI program is most likely not `/root`, but something else. Change the filename to `"/root/pressure.txt"` and see if it works.

Comment: changed it to root and still does not show. The location of the cgi.c file I am working in is sftp://root@10.0.0.2/root/ELEC228Workspace/CGI/src/CGI.c if that helps

Comment: It doesn't really matter where the source file is, not where the executable file is either, what matters is the *current working directory*. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work even when you provide the full path, which means that there is something else wrong. Maybe there just isn't anything in the file? And I don't think the string you read from the file is terminated properly (no `'\0'` at the end) which means you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as long as you treat the buffer as a zero-terminated string.

Comment: [Continuing from previous comment] And if you have undefined behavior, then all of your program is ill-formed and all bets are off in regards to its behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Two important things when writing a CGI program:

- the program will be run by the webserver, which is normally
  started as a different user (the 'www' user for example).
- it's possible that the program is started from within another
  directory, which can cause different behaviour if you don't
  specify the full path of a file you want to open.

Since both these things can cause problems, it can be helpful
to add some debug information. Of course, it's always a good idea
to check return values of functions you use.

To make it easier to display debug or error messages, I'd first
move the following code up, so that all output that comes after
it will be rendered by the browser:

```
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
    puts("<HTML>");
    puts("<BODY>");
```

It may be useful to know what the webserver uses as the directory
from which the program is started. The [`getcwd`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getcwd) 
call can help here. Let's use a buffer of size `BUFFER` to store
the result in, and check if it worked:

```
char curpath[BUFFER];

if (getcwd(curpath, BUFFER) == NULL)
    printf("Can't get current path: %s<BR>\n", strerror(errno));
else
    printf("Current path is: %s<BR>\n", curpath);
```

The `getcwd` function returns NULL in case of an error, and sets the value
of `errno` to a number which indicates what went wrong. To convert this
value to something readable, the [`strerror`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) 
function is used. For example, if `BUFFER` was not large enough to be
able to store the path, you'll see something like

```
Can't get current path: Numerical result out of range
```

The [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) call returns a negative number
if it didn't work, and sets `errno` again. So, to check if this worked:

```
fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
if (fd < 0) 
    printf("Can't open file: %s<BR>\n", strerror(errno));
```

In case the file can be found, but the webserver does not have permission
to open it, you'll see

```
Can't open file: Permission denied
```

If the program is started from another directory than you think, and
it's unable to locate the file, you would get:

```
Can't open file: No such file or directory
```

Adding such debug info should make it more clear what's going on, and more
importantly, what's going wrong.

To make sure the actual data is read without problems as well, the return
value of the [`read`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) function should be 
checked and appropriate actions should be taken. If `read` fails,
a negative number is returned. To handle this:

```
numread = read(fd, buff, BUFFER);
if (numread < 0) 
    printf("Error reading from file: %s<BR>\n", strerror(errno));
```

Another value indicates success, and returns the number of bytes that were
read. If really `BUFFER` bytes were read, it's not at all certain that the
last byte in `buff` is a 0, which is needed for `printf` to know when the
string ended. To make sure it is in fact null-terminated, the last byte in
`buff` is set to 0:

```
if (numread == BUFFER) 
    buff[BUFFER-1] = 0;
```

Note that this actually overwrites one of the bytes that were read in this
case.

If fewer bytes were read, it's still not certain that the last byte that was 
read was a 0, but now we can place our own 0 after the bytes that were read
so none of them are overwritten:

```
else 
    buff[numread] = 0;
```

To make everything work, you may need the following additional include files:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
```

The complete code of what I described is shown below:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int fd, numread;
    char *myfifo = "pressure.txt";
    char buff[BUFFER];
    char curpath[BUFFER];
    long fTemp;

    // Let's make sure all text output (even error/debug messages)
    // will be visible in the web page
    printf("Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n");
    puts("<HTML>");
    puts("<BODY>");

    // Some debug info: print the current path
    if (getcwd(curpath, BUFFER) == NULL)
        printf("Can't get current path: %s<BR>\n", strerror(errno));
    else
        printf("Current path is: %s<BR>\n", curpath);

    // Open the file
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) 
    {
        // An error occurs, let's see what it is
        printf("Can't open file: %s<BR>\n", strerror(errno));
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Try to read 'BUFFER' bytes from the file
        numread = read(fd, buff, BUFFER);
        if (numread < 0) 
        {
            printf("Error reading from file: %s<BR>\n", strerror(errno));
        } 
        else 
        {
            if (numread == BUFFER) 
            {
                // Make sure the last byte in 'buff' is 0, so that the
                // string is null-terminated
                buff[BUFFER-1] = 0;
            } 
            else 
            {
                // Fewer bytes were read, make sure a 0 is placed after 
                // them
                buff[numread] = 0;
            }

            printf("Data is: %s<BR>\n", buff);
        }
        close(fd);
    }

    puts("</BODY>");
    puts("</HTML>");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```